# Insufficient CPU despite autoscaling

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I have a simple Node.js service. Even tough I get an `Insufficient cpu` warning, it eventually works. I think this is because I am using autopilot and new nodes are provided automatically.

```
Starting deploy...
 - deployment.apps/auth-depl configured
 - service/auth-srv configured
 - ingress.networking.k8s.io/ingress-service unchanged
Waiting for deployments to stabilize...
 - deployment/auth-depl: 0/3 nodes are available: 3 Insufficient cpu, 3 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/3 nodes are available: 3 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
    - pod/auth-depl-f746f9cdd-pckr9: 0/3 nodes are available: 3 Insufficient cpu, 3 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/3 nodes are available: 3 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
 - deployment/auth-depl: creating container auth-pod
    - pod/auth-depl-f746f9cdd-pckr9: creating container auth-pod
 - deployment/auth-depl: waiting for rollout to finish: 1 old replicas are pending termination...
 - deployment/auth-depl is ready.
Deployments stabilized in 2 minutes 15.209 seconds
```

I am confused by why CPU limits are being reached when I have a very simple application that returns 'hi' to a GET / request. [full code](https://github.com/bogdan-pechounov/microservices-quiz-app/tree/ab843bbf540506e6cf90e705f4250f0fcd14a902)

If the pod is scaled up, shouldn't the warning stop appearing on subsequent builds?
[image: scale up]

When I add a MongoDB deployment, it works the first time (after deleting the current mongo deployment).

```
#auth-mongo-depl.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mongo-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Mi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-mongo-depl
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth-mongo-pod-label
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth-mongo-pod-label
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongo
          image: mongo
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: storage
              mountPath: /data/db
      volumes:
        - name: storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mongo-pvc
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-mongo-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: auth-mongo-pod-label
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

```
Starting deploy...
 - deployment.apps/auth-depl configured
 - service/auth-srv created
 - persistentvolumeclaim/mongo-pvc unchanged
 - Warning: Autopilot set default resource requests for Deployment default/auth-mongo-depl, as resource requests were not specified. See http://g.co/gke/autopilot-defaults
 - deployment.apps/auth-mongo-depl created
 - service/auth-mongo-srv created
 - ingress.networking.k8s.io/ingress-service unchanged
Waiting for deployments to stabilize...
 - deployment/auth-depl: 0/3 nodes are available: 3 Insufficient cpu, 3 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/3 nodes are available: 3 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
    - pod/auth-depl-7cf7878d76-t666t: 0/3 nodes are available: 3 Insufficient cpu, 3 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/3 nodes are available: 3 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
 - deployment/auth-mongo-depl: 0/3 nodes are available: 3 Insufficient cpu, 3 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/3 nodes are available: 3 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
    - pod/auth-mongo-depl-8f5997d87-5gqwd: 0/3 nodes are available: 3 Insufficient cpu, 3 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/3 nodes are available: 3 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
 - deployment/auth-depl is ready. [1/2 deployment(s) still pending]
 - deployment/auth-mongo-depl is ready.
Deployments stabilized in 2 minutes 35.184 seconds
You can also run [skaffold run --tail] to get the logs

Help improve Skaffold with our 2-minute anonymous survey: run 'skaffold survey'
To help improve the quality of this product, we collect anonymized usage data for details on what is tracked and how we use this data visit <https://skaffold.dev/docs/resources/telemetry/>. This data is handled in accordance with our privacy policy <https://policies.google.com/privacy>

You may choose to opt out of this collection by running the following command:
        skaffold config set --global collect-metrics false
PUSH
DONE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID                                    CREATE_TIME                DURATION  SOURCE                                                           
                                 IMAGES  STATUS
5ae8bbcc-ab76-4994-b700-af0d7c99598f  2023-03-15T16:02:35+00:00  3M12S     gs://disco-ethos-380514_cloudbuild/source/1678895981.530669-3ad4d45463f54be2954ab1cfe3387583.tgz  -       SUCCESS
```

[image: pod details]

I am not sure why the scheduling would fail 3 times and attaching the volume would fail at first.

(I just realized the "does not contain driver" error, but the documentation says it should be enabled.

> The Compute Engine persistent disk CSI Driver is always enabled in
> Autopilot clusters and can't be disabled or edited. - [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/gce-pd-csi-driver)

[image: driver enabled]
)

However, for the next build, it doesn't work.

```
Starting deploy...
 - deployment.apps/auth-depl configured
 - service/auth-srv configured
 - persistentvolumeclaim/mongo-pvc unchanged
 - deployment.apps/auth-mongo-depl configured
 - service/auth-mongo-srv configured
 - ingress.networking.k8s.io/ingress-service unchanged
Waiting for deployments to stabilize...
 - deployment/auth-depl: 0/4 nodes are available: 4 Insufficient cpu, 4 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/4 nodes are available: 4 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
    - pod/auth-depl-6fd9ffcbb4-rrbdp: 0/4 nodes are available: 4 Insufficient cpu, 4 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/4 nodes are available: 4 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
 - deployment/auth-mongo-depl: 0/4 nodes are available: 4 Insufficient cpu, 4 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/4 nodes are available: 4 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
    - pod/auth-mongo-depl-79b5cfb9d7-z99xv: 0/4 nodes are available: 4 Insufficient cpu, 4 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/4 nodes are available: 4 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
 - deployment/auth-depl: creating container auth-pod
    - pod/auth-depl-6fd9ffcbb4-rrbdp: creating container auth-pod
 - deployment/auth-mongo-depl: Unschedulable: 0/1 nodes available: 1 node is not ready
    - pod/auth-mongo-depl-79b5cfb9d7-z99xv: Unschedulable: 0/1 nodes available: 1 node is not ready
 - deployment/auth-depl is ready. [1/2 deployment(s) still pending]
 - deployment/auth-mongo-depl: creating container mongo
    - pod/auth-mongo-depl-79b5cfb9d7-z99xv: creating container mongo
 - deployment/auth-mongo-depl failed. Error: creating container mongo.
1/2 deployment(s) failed
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/k8s-skaffold/skaffold:v2.2.0" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

BUILD FAILURE: Build step failure: build step 0 "gcr.io/k8s-skaffold/skaffold:v2.2.0" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) build 16b405f8-bce8-4851-ad9b-d67974fc39ae completed with status "FAILURE"
```

The second pod is stuck in "ContainerCreating".
[image: 2 pods]

[image: failed mount]

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67177464/20898396) answer, failing to mount was a bug. I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75385283/20898396), but I am still confused why it works for the first build and not on subsequent ones.

---

The other answers I find such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44930622/20898396) one involve changing some settings, but I have auto scaling enabled to hide this complexity.

[image: auto scaling]

I doubt I am reaching any [quota limits](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-resource-requests#defaults). The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes#persistentvolumeclaims) about PVCs doesn't mention enabling something manually.

Edit: It seems the issue is with `ReadWriteOnce` as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46893114/20898396). Many pods can read while only one can write, but this is all within a single node. During the building phase, the same node cannot be reused because of taint, which leads to two nodes accessing the same volume. I tried using `ReadWriteMany`.

```
Starting deploy...
 - deployment.apps/auth-depl configured
 - service/auth-srv configured
 - persistentvolumeclaim/auth-mongo-pvc created
 - Warning: Autopilot set default resource requests for Deployment default/auth-mongo-depl, as resource requests were not specified. See http://g.co/gke/autopilot-defaults
 - deployment.apps/auth-mongo-depl created
 - service/auth-mongo-srv created
 - deployment.apps/react-client-depl configured
 - service/react-client-srv configured
 - ingress.networking.k8s.io/ingress-service configured
Waiting for deployments to stabilize...
 - deployment/auth-depl: 0/4 nodes are available: 4 Insufficient cpu, 4 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/4 nodes are available: 4 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
    - pod/auth-depl-55b48d8f5b-fzq9c: 0/4 nodes are available: 4 Insufficient cpu, 4 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/4 nodes are available: 4 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
 - deployment/auth-mongo-depl: 0/4 nodes are available: 4 Insufficient cpu, 4 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/4 nodes are available: 4 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
    - pod/auth-mongo-depl-6c8cc4dd4c-jdzxw: 0/4 nodes are available: 4 Insufficient cpu, 4 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/4 nodes are available: 4 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
 - deployment/react-client-depl: 0/4 nodes are available: 4 Insufficient cpu, 4 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/4 nodes are available: 4 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
    - pod/react-client-depl-59d7d8fd7-drlhg: 0/4 nodes are available: 4 Insufficient cpu, 4 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/4 nodes are available: 4 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
 - deployment/react-client-depl: Unschedulable: 0/1 nodes available: 1 node is not ready
    - pod/react-client-depl-59d7d8fd7-drlhg: Unschedulable: 0/1 nodes available: 1 node is not ready
 - deployment/auth-depl is ready. [2/3 deployment(s) still pending]
 - deployment/react-client-depl is ready. [1/3 deployment(s) still pending]
 - deployment/auth-mongo-depl: Unschedulable: 0/1 nodes available: 1 node is not ready
    - pod/auth-mongo-depl-6c8cc4dd4c-jdzxw: Unschedulable: 0/1 nodes available: 1 node is not ready
 - deployment/auth-mongo-depl failed. Error: Unschedulable: 0/1 nodes available: 1 node is not ready.
1/3 deployment(s) failed
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/k8s-skaffold/skaffold:v2.2.0" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

[image: NotTriggerScaleUp]

Comment: I would suggest contacting the Support team to look into your project for further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick fix, do not use rolling updates.

```
spec:
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
```

[details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58348986/20898396)